# error when importing modules with es2015 syntax and babel transpilation to es5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

I got problems with transpiling es2015 code to to ES5. Problem happens with module imports:

```
import * as express from "express"
```

is transpiled to:

```
var _express = require("express");
var express = _interopRequireWildcard(_express);
```

Which cause the error:

```
var app = express();
          ^
TypeError: express is not a function
```

But if I import with

> var express = require('express');

all works fine.

I still want to use es2015 syntax, is there a setting or plugin I should  Install in bable to have it work properly ?

Comment: How are you using `express`?

Comment: Looks like you should be doing `import express from "express";` when express doesn't support ES6 modules yet

Comment: it's not related to express specifically, it's  general issue with modul import. Your solution works, altough it says express doesn't have a default export.

Comment: Yes, importing non-ES6 modules is a general issue :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
import express from "express"
```

Comment: I upgraded to node js 6 which supposedly support all es6 features, and even my own files report 'unexpected' tokens.... why is that ?

Comment: Node 6 does not support all ES6 features, it does support the vast majority of them though.